# How do you get the number of bytes in a Redshift field?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, defining the the proper width for VARCHAR columns is very important, however, I cannot find a way to query the number of bytes in a field!

When only dealing with ASCII you can use LEN(), but for UTF-8, LEN() will undercount the number of bytes.  LEN() * 4 is a worst case scenario, but it is particularly inefficient.

In vanilla Postgresql, this can be accomplished with octet_length(), but this is deprecated in Redshift.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a Python function in order to get number of bytes in a field. Maybe it'll help you

```
create or replace function dbadmin.get_utf8_bytes(param1 varchar(max))
returns int
stable AS $$
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
return len(param1.encode('utf-8'))
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Next you need to pass your field to this function, for example:

```
SELECT dbadmin.get_utf8_bytes(your_field)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea about python UDFs, so when I looked at your solution I was pretty confused.  Thanks for the solution and for showing me a great example of a python UDF!  

Also, I needed to remove the 'dbadmin' prefix from the method name or else I got an error.

Comment: No problems! Yes, instead of schema 'dbadmin' you have to use your schema name. When objects are created without a specific target schema, they are placed in the first schema listed in the search path. If the search path is empty, the system returns an error https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html

Answer (score 0):

Redshift added [OCTET_LENGTH()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_OCTET_LENGTH.html) in 2017. This is now the most performant way to get the number of bytes in a Redshift field.

Example:

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(your_field) FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Interesting info: `OCTET_LENGTH` seems it will treat input numbers as string as well. While this may be fine for `varchar` columns, using it for `decimal` columns can give you incorrect number.